# Name of character arrays prints the whole array instead of its address

Tags: c++11

We have learned that in case of an array like `int a[]={1,2,3};` if we print a as `cout<<a;` then it prints the address of the first element of the array. But for character array `char a[]="Jayesha";` when we do `cout<<a;` it prints the whole array instead of its address. Also if we print `&a[0]` it prints 'Jayesha', `&a[1]` prints 'ayesha', `&a[2]` prints 'yesha', `&a[3]` prints 'esha' and so on...

*Can anybody please explain why that happens??*

Comment: You should read up on `operator<<` and work out what `std::cout << ...` actually does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const char* a = "Jajesha";` points to a c-style char string. In memory it looks like

```
J  a  j  e  s  h  a  \0 ???
^
a
^     ^           ^     ^
&a[0] &a[2]       &a[6] &a[8]
   ^     ^           ^
   &a[1] &a[3]       &a[7]
```

You are doing some pointer arithmetics.
`&a[x]` is equivalent to `a+x`.
And it will be of type `const char *`.

When accessing beyond the length, in your case >7 chars, the result is undefined and may crash

a `cout<<` of a `const char *` will output all chars until it finds a `\0`

Comment: I think you mean const char*

Answer (score 0):

This is due to operator overloading, explained [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

In your two cases, either you're printing a `const void*`, the address or you're printing `const char*`, the contents of the string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different overloads of `std::ostream& <<` that are being used here.

The first is `std::ostream& << void const*`, the second is `std::ostream << const char*`.  All pointers can convertable to `void const*`, and arrays convert to pointers-to-their-first-element.

So when you pass an array of non-character data to `<<`, its best match is the `void const*` overload, which prints the address.

When you pass an array of character data to `<<`, its best match is the `char const*` overload.  That version assumes it has a pointer to a null-terminated strings and prints that buffer.

To avoid this, do a `static_cast<void*>` on the array prior to passing it to `<<`.